# css position web design

Tags: javascript, html, css, qlikview

I have to make changes in some `CSS` and a Javascript file.
I have a header row and some columns and when I scale the object the header isn't in line with columns anymore. So I have to fix the header with columns and they are in different classes of the `CSS` . here is the link of the [picture](http://s13.postimg.org/6795sp72v/Untitledsda.png).
These are codes of Qlikview.

```
.c6graph {  

margin-left: 7px;
margin-top: 5px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
 }

    /* Start of "Micro clearfix" */

    .cf { zoom: 0; }
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after { content: ""; display: table; }
    .cf:after { clear: both; }

    /* End of "Micro clearfix" */


       .e6headerrow {
           font-size:8pt; 
            font-family:Tahoma;
           font-weight:bold;

          padding: 5px;}

       .e6firstcolumn {
            text-align: left;
            width: 14% !Important;
            max-width: 14%; 
            min-width: 14%;}
      .e6thirdforthcolumn {display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
         width: 43% !Important;
        max-width: 43%; 
        min-width: 43%;}
```

`
and here is the javascript part that calles this css classes

```
    var html = "<table class='c6graph cf' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><colgroup ><col      class='e6headerrow e6firstcolumn''/><col class='e6headerrow e6thirdforthcolumn'/><col class='e6headerrow e6thirdforthcolumn'/></colgroup>"; 

      html += "<tr>" + firstColumnHeader + "<td class='e6headerrow e6thirdforthcolumn' >" + thirdColumnValue + "</td><td class='e6headerrow e6thirdforthcolumn' >" + fourthColumnValue + "</td></tr>";
    htmlFirstColumn = "<td class='e6thirdforthcolumn' ><div class='ext neg'><div style='width: " 
            + widthValue1 + ";' class='bar " + (isSwitchBorder == 1 ? "border-neg" : "") + "'></div><div class='progressneg " + progressRounded + "'>" + row[1].text + "</div></div></td>"; 
        }
        else {
            htmlFirstColumn = "<td class='e6thirdforthcolumn' ><div class='ext pos'><div style='width: " 
            + widthValue1 + ";' class='bar "+ (isSwitchBorder == 1 ? "border-pos" : "") + "'></div><div class='progresspos  " + progressRounded + "'>" + row[1].text + "</div></div></td>";
        }

        var widthValue2 = Math.abs(parseInt(row[2].text))*factorTotvar + "%";
        var htmlSecondColumn = "";
        if(row[2].text.substring(0,1) == "-") {
            htmlSecondColumn = "<td class='e6thirdforthcolumn' ><div class='ext neg'><div style='width: " 
            + widthValue2 + ";' class='bar "+ (isSwitchBorder == 1 ? "border-neg" : "") + "'></div><div class='progressneg  " + progressRounded3 + "'>" + row[2].text + "</div></div></td>";    
        }
        else {
            htmlSecondColumn = "<td class='e6thirdforthcolumn' ><div class='ext pos'><div style='width: " 
            + widthValue2 + ";' class='bar "+ (isSwitchBorder == 1 ? "border-pos" : "") + "'></div><div class='progresspos  " + progressRounded3 + "'>" + row[2].text + "</div></div></td>";
        }


        var firstColumnRow = (isDimensionEnabled != 1 ? "<td class='e6firstcolumn'>" + dimensionBolded + "</td>" : "");
        html += "<tr>" + firstColumnRow;
        html +=htmlFirstColumn;
        html +=htmlSecondColumn;
        html +="</tr>";
```

Comment: This code isn't very readable... Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: it has to be like in the picture ... i posted above... Do u know any tehniks  to do that?
i dont know if i can  do that in JSFiddle cause it contains qlikview elements?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm one point show of being able to comment, so I'll post this as an answer.

Your javascript portion is missing pieces of code, the definition of the variable firstColumnHeader and the first half of an if then else around the the htmlFirstColumn.  I'm assuming it's missing from a cut and paste error and not bad code since you have some output.

It would help if instead of posting the javascript that builds the html, if you do a view source and paste the html code that is generated by the javascript.

From what I can see, it looks like you aren't formatting the column heading and the table column the same way, and that would be why they aren't rendering exactly the same.